# Asp.net, directly assigning properties from value?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to express

```
<% objControl.ObjProp=ObjVar; %>
<my:Control ID="objControl" runat="server" />
```

As something like this, in one line? And without passing ObjVar as a string?

```
<my:Control ID="objControl" runat="server" ObjProp=ObjVar />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're in a databound context, no there's no simple way to do this. If it is a databound context (Like in a repeater/gridview) you can simply go ObjProp='<%# ObjVar %>', but outside that context you can't do it inline unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

use it like

```
<my:Control ID="objControl" runat="server" ObjProp="<%# ObjVar %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As fyjham has mentioned, you need to do this in a databound context with the <%#  %> syntax. If you are trying to set the property dynamically then your other option is to set it within the server side parent's onload code behind method.

Answer (score 0):

What is ObjVar? If it's a static value, you can just add the attribute tag to the control element like so....

```
<my:Control ID="objControl" runat="server" MyCustomBooleanProperty="true" />
```

If it's a member variable of the page containing the control, then I'd do so in the code behind...

```
protected Page_Init()
{
    this.objControl.ObjProp = this.ObjVar;
}
```

If you're databinding to the control, then the others are correct where you use the databinding context.

```
<my:Control ID="objControl" runat="server" ObjProp=<%#Eval("ObjVar")%> />
```